# A case of efficiency in the simplest of loops

Tags: java, c++

Suppose there is a loop in which there is an integer variable named `counter` that needs to be reset to 0 for every iteration. Which of the two versions would be more efficient?

**Version-1:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     int counter = 0; 
     if (something()) counter++;
}
```

**Version-2:**

```
int counter;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     counter = 0; 
     if (something()) counter++;
}
```

In the first version, the scope of the counter variable is within the for loop and it's reallocated in memory for every iteration. In the second case, it is just overwritten on a single memory location throughout the program. I think the second version is more efficient but is the efficiency negligible or considerable or is it the other way around?

Comment: Compiler/JIT will probably turn #2 to #1 anyway

Comment: For which language? On what operating system? And what platform and version? In short, the answer is *negligible* and beware premature optimization.

Comment: I expect that you won't find ANY difference at all - modern compilers will figure out how you are using `counter` in both of these cases and generate identical code.

Comment: (Obviously, the second case allows you to put 10000 lines of code after the loop, and THEN use `counter`, but for the given examples, I'd actually expect counter to disappear, since it is not used for anything. If your compiler/JIT isn't clever enough to figure that out, you should upgrade/replace/investigate alternatives.

Comment: In theory,  version 2 is faster,but as stated above,  with modern compiler optimizations, there will be no difference.

Comment: yea, both of them are doing the same thing really, but in my opinion, Version 2, because you are recycling the counter value by overriding it or recycling it, than in version one where you are dumping the old counter value and creating a new one every time you start the loop.

Comment: Java or C++? Better pick one language.

Comment: Both. How about Java and C++? What happens in each case?

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, counter will *not* be reallocated in memory on every iteration. It's a variable of a primitive type (int), so most compilers will store it on the stack. There is no reason to use a different stack location for different iterations on the loop, so it will be stored in the same location, just like in the second version.

(This assumes that the compiler does not elide the `counter` variable entirely, because you're not using its value anywhere.)

Comment: Upvoted to cancel our lacraig2's downvote, this answer is correct. There's no "reallocation".

Comment: @Blindy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site

Comment: Fine, then upvoting because it's correct? What exactly do you want here?